# Camera Preview Layer not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, camera, swift-playground

I am Creating an App with a Custom Camera View in swift but the view is just black
it seems that thelive preview window is not showing up, This is not working in my Xcode app, swift playgrounds on the iPad, and swift playgrounds on the mac.
here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
import CoreFoundation
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

let view = UIView()
var str = "Hello, playground"
import PlaygroundSupport
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?







captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
var backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType:     AVMediaTypeVideo)
 var error: NSError?
 //var lol = AVCaptureInput();
 // var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera, error: &error)

 var input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)

//error

if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
    captureSession!.addInput(input)
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
//    stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

}

 previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
 view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
 previewLayer!.frame = view.bounds
 PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
 //PlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Comment: In the app, are you requesting camera authorization from the user?

Comment: yup, and the user agrees and its just a black view

Answer (score 1):

One issue I can see with your code is that you never start the Capture Session. To this run use `captureSession.startRunning()`

Comment: I'm not ashamed to admit I made the same mistake. Thanks @Zekep